# Refering to a table without class/id

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to refer to a table by using beautifulsoup and python 3, but the table doesn't has a class nor id. this is the html of the top layer. how can I identify the table?

Answer (score 1):

you can refer table without id/class using xpath

```
//*[./text()="SKU#"]/ancestor::table[1]
```

hope this resolves